# Java scanner delimiter error csv java end of line

Tags: java, csv, delimiter, inputmismatchexception

I'm receiving an `InputMismatchException` while scanning in the last int of a csv.

```
public class TradeSim {
    public void readFile(String fileName) {
        try {
            // file name and absolute path
            File file = new File(fileName);
            String fullPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
            System.out.println("Using file:\n" + fullPath + "\n");

            // set File Input Stream to Full Path
            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fullPath);

            // open input stream and retrieve data
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputStream);
            scanner.useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                String data = scanner.next(); // gets a whole line
                System.out.println(data);
                parseCSVLine(data);
            }
            scanner.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Encountered Error reading file:\n" + e.toString() + "\n");
        }
    }

    public void parseCSVLine(String line) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(line);
        scanner.useDelimiter(",");
        long timeStamp = scanner.nextLong();
        System.out.println("timeStamp: " + timeStamp);
        String symbol = scanner.next();
        System.out.println("symbol: " + symbol);
        int quantity = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("quantity: " + quantity);
        int price = scanner.nextInt(); //Error occurs here!!
        System.out.println("price: " + price);
        Trades trades = new Trades(timeStamp, symbol, quantity, price);
    }
}
```

File content:

> 51300051409,fbc,273,297
>   51300073658,cef,250,262

Output:

> Using file:
>   /Users/andrewkeithly/netbeansprojects/Trades Exercise/input.csv
>
> 51300051409,fbc,273,297
>   timeStamp: 51300051409
>   symbol: fbc
>   quantity: 273
>   Encountered Error reading file:
>   java.util.InputMismatchException

Comment: maybe its not an int at that position. include the whole scanning process in a try catch block first of all and preferably use  scanner.next(). later you can parse as needed

Comment: @AbtPst Thanks for your response! The line it is reading is: <51300051409,fbc,273,297> It scans the first 3 and is unable to scan the final int 297. The whole scanning process is in a try catch block which calls the parseCSVLine method.

Comment: does it work if you use next()?

Comment: Nope, that was the first thing I tried. I think it has to do with the end of line delimiter.

Comment: @andrewkeithly welcome to SO.  Any time you are looking for help on an exception it is useful to post the stack trace and corresponding line in your code sample.

Comment: Thanks @MartinSerrano, I've posted the full code along with error.

Comment: Can you provide an example file content which causes the exception? And can you please post the _whole_ exception?

Comment: @Tom I've updated the code to better illustrate my issue.

Comment: Your code works fine for me _if_ the file is written with the correct line delimiter. Either the file was written "for" Unix and you're on Windows or vice versa.

Comment: Thanks @Tom, I think you may be correct. I'm on a Unix machine and the csv was likely written "for" Windows. I'm investigating now.

Comment: Wow. What a silly error… I was using System.getProperty("line.separator") which was referencing a specific Unix delimiter. Problem solved!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Problem Solved:**
`System.getProperty("line.separator")` was looking for a Unix specific delimiter in which the csv did not use.
Simply changing the code to `scanner.useDelimiter("\r?\n");` solved my problem. Thanks @Tom !

Comment: Please don't use `useDelimiter(" ")` which looks like it will cause more trouble. Use `useDelimiter("\r?\n")` instead. It reads `"\r"` if it is there and it definitely reads `"\n"`, so works for both, Unix and Windows.